# how to use tag a replace input submit?

Tags: jquery

i am use this code

```
document.getElementById('frmLogin').submit()
```

this is work and send form but validation not working!
when use `input type="submit"` validation work in asp.net mvc

Comment: where is the validation logic added

Comment: try `jQuery('#frmLogin').submit()`

Comment: 1 tip: jquery-validate requires that every input has a name-attribute, when it doesn't have that, it just tells the validator it is valid

Comment: Which validation are you talking about? client side or server site?

Comment: i am use asp.net mvc validation jquery.validate.js,jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js ,...

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead to trigger validation before submitting the form:

```
document.getElementById('btnSubmit').click();
```

Where `btnSubmit` is the ID of the submit button, e.g.

```
<input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" />
```

The above should imitate exactly a button click.